# ValueError: Cannot assign "'Category'": "Course.category" must be a "Category" instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, django-rest-framework

У меня проблема с запуском кода, когда я пытаюсь запустить юнит-тесты. Любым решениям данной проблемы буду искренне благодарен)

Code from tests.py:

```
class CourseTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_category(name="English", imgpath="ImgPath"):
        return Category.objects.create(name=name, imgpath=imgpath)

    def setUp(self):
        Course.objects.create(
            name='English',
            description='Sample text',
            category_id=self.create_category().id,
            logo='Logo'
        )

    def test_course_category(self):
        english = Course.objects.get(name='English')
        self.assertEqual(english.category_id, 1)
```

Models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    imgpath = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    logo = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'Category'": "Course.category" must be a "Category" instance.

Comment: `models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)` -- передача в качестве первого параметра класса, а не объекта класса происходит. Так точно должно быть? Судя по сообщению об ошибке, это может быть проблемой

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как решить данную проблему? Потому что сама API работает корректно

Comment: Похоже, я был неправ, с джанго плохо знаком. Единственное, в строке `category_id=self.create_category().id` -- не должно ли быть просто `category_id=self.create_category()`. Нечто похожее в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840037

Comment: Я пробовал данный метод, все равно компилятор возвращает данную ошибку в том же виде

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
Course.objects.create(
    ...
    category=self.create_category(),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Только что пробовал данный способ, та же самая ошибка(

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил, надеюсь на вашу помощь, буду благодарен)